# how to union two tables that starts with temporary table logic BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, union, temp-tables, union-all

I have two tables that I need to union. Both of them have the same logic, just different source tables. Query looks like this:

```
with origin_table as (
    SELECT
        date,
        (
            SELECT
                value
            FROM
                UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)
            WHERE
                INDEX = 10
        ) AS second_scroll,
        (
            SELECT
                value
            FROM
                UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)
            WHERE
                INDEX = 11
        ) AS dwell
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                date,
                hits,
            FROM
                `table_1`,
                UNNEST(hits) AS hits
        )
    GROUP BY
        1
    select
        date,
        case
            when second_scroll is not null
            AND dwell is not null then 1
            when second_scroll is null
            AND dwell is not null then 0
            when second_scroll is not null
            AND dwell is null then 0
        end as ENGAGEMENT
    from
        origin_table
```

This query works perfectly fine, but when I add the same exact query below that is pulling data from `table_2` and use `UNION ALL` I have the following error: `Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT but got keyword WITH` So the queries can not start with `with table as`. Now to UNION two tables with this logic?

Comment: write 2 CTE's first then union the results in the final  `With CTE1 as (SELECT), CTE2 as (Select) SELECT * from CTE1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM CTE2`  assuming CTE1 and CTE2 have same structure

Comment: Does @xQbert suggestion answered your question?

Comment: That doesn't work...

Comment: @Chique_Code  I need more to go on then it doesn't work.  Logically it should.  Are you getting the same error, can you post the Final SQL you tried?  Are you sure the datatypes are the same, column counts are the same and the collation is the same?  Are you sure the individual selects work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this would be close...  Need more detail to the nature of your problem or an ability to recreate it to isolate the issue...

```
with origin_table as (
    SELECT
        date,
        (
            SELECT
                value
            FROM
                UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)
            WHERE
                INDEX = 10
        ) AS second_scroll,
        (
            SELECT
                value
            FROM
                UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)
            WHERE
                INDEX = 11
        ) AS dwell
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                date,
                hits,
            FROM
                `table_1`,
                UNNEST(hits) AS hits
        )
    GROUP BY
        1),  --added the comma for 2nd cte.

 origin_table2 as ( --Begin 2nd CTE
    SELECT
        date,
        (
            SELECT
                value
            FROM
                UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)
            WHERE
                INDEX = 10
        ) AS second_scroll,
        (
            SELECT
                value
            FROM
                UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)
            WHERE
                INDEX = 11
        ) AS dwell
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                date,
                hits,
            FROM
                `table_2`,  --changed to table 2
                UNNEST(hits) AS hits
        )
    GROUP BY
        1)

    select
        date,
        case
            when second_scroll is not null
            AND dwell is not null then 1
            when second_scroll is null
            AND dwell is not null then 0
            when second_scroll is not null
            AND dwell is null then 0
        end as ENGAGEMENT
    from
        origin_table
    UNION ALL  --here's the union 
    select
        date,
        case
            when second_scroll is not null
            AND dwell is not null then 1
            when second_scroll is null
            AND dwell is not null then 0
            when second_scroll is not null
            AND dwell is null then 0
        end as ENGAGEMENT
    from
        origin_table2 --and selecting from 2nd CTE to union...
```